# Flash builder code navigation failing

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am experiencing a problem with Flash Builder.
It only seems to occur when setting `output folder` and `output folder url` build path properties to a path that is basically a reference to a JBoss folder location.

- Everything compiles and runs fine, however code navigation with
  `CTRL+CLICK` shows a `Source could not be found for <path>.swc` error:

[image]

- Project layout: A main application + 1 Library project

[image]

- The build path for the main application:

[image]

- The build path for the library project:

[image]

- The classes included for the library project:

[image]

- Content of Main application mxml:

  ```
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
             minWidth="955" 
             minHeight="600" 
             xmlns:local="*" 
             xmlns:test="be.some.test.*">
       <fx:Declarations>
          <test:SomeLibraryComponent/> <!--ctrl + click failing-->
       </fx:Declarations>
    </s:Application>
  ```
- The `.actionScriptProperties` file of the Main application:

  ```
  <actionScriptProperties analytics="false" mainApplicationPath="TestCodeNavi.mxml" projectUUID="d4c352fe-5d3a-454e-bb58-db0d96bd9edd" version="10">
     <compiler additionalCompilerArguments="-locale en_US" autoRSLOrdering="true" copyDependentFiles="true" fteInMXComponents="false" generateAccessible="true" htmlExpressInstall="true" htmlGenerate="true" htmlHistoryManagement="true" htmlPlayerVersionCheck="true" includeNetmonSwc="false" outputFolderLocation="MIRAGE_JBOSS_SERVER/deploy/mirage-server.war/TestCodeNavi" outputFolderPath="bin-debug" removeUnusedRSL="true" rootURL="http://localhost:8080/mirage-server/TestCodeNavi" sourceFolderPath="src" strict="true" targetPlayerVersion="0.0.0" useApolloConfig="false" useDebugRSLSwfs="true" verifyDigests="true" warn="true">
  <compilerSourcePath/>
  <libraryPath defaultLinkType="0">
    <libraryPathEntry kind="4" path="">
      <excludedEntries>
        <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
        <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/core.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      </excludedEntries>
    </libraryPathEntry>
    <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="/TestCodeNaviLibrary/bin-debug/TestCodeNaviLibrary.swc" sourcepath="/TestCodeNaviLibrary" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
  </libraryPath>
  <sourceAttachmentPath>
    <sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="/TestCodeNaviLibrary/bin-debug/TestCodeNaviLibrary.swc" sourcepath="/TestCodeNaviLibrary" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
  </sourceAttachmentPath>
    </compiler>
    <applications>
      <application path="TestCodeNavi.mxml"/>
     </applications>
     <modules/>
     <buildCSSFiles/>
    <flashCatalyst validateFlashCatalystCompatibility="false"/>
   </actionScriptProperties>
  ```

Would really appreciate some pointers on this one.

Cheers

Comment: Since both projects are in the same workspace; instead of adding the SWC to the library path; try adding the project.

Comment: I thought I was doing exactly that? @see section: The build path for the main application

Comment: You're right; my mistake for not reviewing the screenshots closely enough.  I'm not sure why this would occur.

Comment: When adding them without the output folder url and output folder, it works just fine so your remark would have been valid for that case.

Comment: You may just want to file a bug report with Adobe on this one. FB has always had some quirks, but v4.7 is really bug-ridden: I just helped out a colleague by adding assets to be included in a swc directly to the .flexLibProperties file, because it has become impossible to do so from the UI. I'm a total IntelliJ convert now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Close all the project in Flash Builder
2. Open .actionScriptProperties file in notepad++ and review the library path and source path. If you find any extra entry in library path, you can remove it, save the file and Open Flash Builder again.

Also the other issue could be, check in the library project "Classes" tab that you have selected all the classes, that needs to be included in the project.

Comment: Could you elaborte on what you mean by "extra entry"? Currently there is only one, which seems okay to me. Updated my question to contain .actionscript properties. My library sources are set to "inlude all"